# Integration is unevaluated analytically after a variable removed

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I am using Mathematica 9.0 to do a symbolic integration as follows:

```
Integrate[(C^y (D - t*y))/(A*C^y + 
  B*C^((1 + z) N/4) (C^(-y) + C^y)), {y, 0, z*N/2}, 
  Assumptions :> {N > 0, 0 < z < 1, D > 0, 1 > C > 0, A > 0, B > 0, t > 0}]
```

The solution is given as:

```
(* (Log[C] (N^2 t z^2 Log[C] + 2 N t z Log[A + B C^(1/4 N (1 + z))] - 4 D Log[A + 2 B C^(1/4 N (1 + z))] + 
  4 D Log[A C^(N z) + B C^(1/4 N (1 + z)) (1 + C^(N z))] - 
  2 N t z Log[A C^(N z) + B C^(1/4 N (1 + z)) (1 + C^(N z))]) - 2 t PolyLog[2, -((B C^(1/4 N (1 + z)))/(A + B C^(1/4 N (1 + z))))] + 2 t PolyLog[2, -((B C^(1/4 (N - 3 N z)))/(A + B C^(1/4 N (1 + z))))])/(8 (A + B C^(1/4 N (1 + z))) Log[C]^2) *)
```

But when I remove the variable `N` or let `N = 1`, the integration become unevaluated.
I don't quite understand why here. Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: It is hazardous to use upper case characters as variable names. "C", "D", and "N" all have defined uses in Mathematica. Use lower case.

Comment: I changed all variable name to lower case. The issue remains.

Comment: `Integrate` returns unevaluated in version 10.1 for the code as displayed in the question or with all upper case letters (except in `Integrate`) replaced by lower case letters.

Comment: @Amos5, with version 8.0 "Integrate" also returns unevaluated.  But the solution you give must be right, because with the rule-based-integrator of Albert Rich "Rubi 4.11" (http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) I get a solution with the same numerical results for given parameters, although "FullSimplify" can't proof the identity.  Therefore simply set N=1 in your solution, if you don't need it.